# Example of extern global variable - Error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, global-variables, extern

I'd like to understand which mistake i did in the following example. There are three file: main.c, libreria_mia.c and libreria_mia.h.

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libreria_mia.h"

int x = 5;

int main()
{
    int y = quadrato();
    printf("%d\n", y);
    return 0;
}


// libreria_mia.h
extern int x;
int quadrato(void);


// libreria_mia.c
int quadrato(void)
{
    x = x * x;
}
```

Error:

```
libreria_mia.c:5:2: error: ‘x’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: how do you compile/ link them?

Comment: What problems do you have with the code you show? If you get build errors, then please copy-paste them (as text, and in full and complete) into the question body.

Comment: Did you include `libreria_mia.h` in `libreria_mia.c`?

Comment: As a hint: Where in  `libreria_mia.c` are you declaring the variable `x`?

Comment: Hello @SouravGhosh i wrote a makefile to compile and link the files.

Comment: Hi @klutt i included libreria_mia.h only in the main.c; if I wrote the function int quadrato(int a){return a=a*a;}, it works also if i don't include libreria_mia.h in libreria_mia.c

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i define x in the main.c as a global variable

Comment: You need to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) . The compiler will treat a single source file (with all included header files) as a single independent unit. It will not know anything about variables declared (or defined) in other translation units. The `extern int x;` declaration needs to be inside the `libreria_mia.c` translation unit to be able to recognize the variable `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile libreria_mia.c, the compiler does not automatically know about libreria_mia.h or the declarations within it. To provide a declaration for `x` while compiling libreria_mia.c, libreria_mia.c must include a header that declares `x` or have a declaration of `x` directly in libreria_mia.c.

Additionally, it is conventional for a header named *file*.h to declare things defined in *file*.c (not necessarily all things defined in *file*.c, just those intended to be used outside it). But you have `x` declared in libreria_mia.h but defined in main.c. Normally, one would either define `x` in libreria_mia.c or declare it in main.h, and usually the former as main.c is more commonly a user of all other things in the program rather than a provider.

Comment: Hello @EricPostpischil so is it sufficient to write #include "libreria_mia.h" in the file libreria_mia.c?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi — Yes. Add `#include “libreria_mia.h”` to the `.c` file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: @EricPostpischil great explanation.